# Filter elements in a DOM with common 'class' name and apply CSS on it - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a DOM, I could filter out elements having class names starting with a particular word, here it is `answer_list_two cpts_` and the result is given below.

```
$('[class^="answer_list_two cpts_"]') =>
```

`[<div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_1_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_2_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_3_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_4_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_5_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_1_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_2_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_3_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_4_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_5_19234">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_1_19235">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_2_19235">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_3_19235">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_1_19235">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_2_19235">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"answer_list_two cpts_3_19235">​…​</div>​]`

from this, I would like to take an element, find its `class name`, find another element having **same class name**, compare the `height` of both the DIV elements and apply the larger height value to both the DIV elements. Please help me with the JQuery code for implementing the same. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var filtered = {}, $els = $('.answer_list_two[class*="cpts_"]');
$els.each(function () {
    var clazz = this.className.match(/cpts_\d+_\d+/)[0];
    if (filtered[clazz]) {
        return;
    }

    var height = 0;
    $els.filter('.' + clazz).each(function () {
        var h = $(this).height();
        if (height < h) {
            height = h;
        }
    }).height(height);
    filtered[clazz] = true;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ggy9sLwe/)

Answer (score 2):

Take this as start (unproved), let me now if I should change something.

```
var classs;
$('[class^="answer_list_two cpts_"]').each(function(index, val) {
    classs = val.attr('class');
    $('.'+classs).each(function(index2, val2) {
        if(val.height() > val2.height()){
            val2.css('height', val.height());
        } else {
            val.css('height', val2.height())
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would just do something like a comparison:

```
function compareHeight($el, $el2){
    var h1 = $el.height();
    var h2 = $el2.height();
    var h = h1 > h2 ? h1 : h2

    $el.css('height', h);
    $el2.css('height', h);
}

var $items = $('.class');

if($items.length > 1){
    compareHeight($items.eq(0), $items.eq(1));
}
```

I'm not sure what logic you want to use to get the elements, but select them however you want and pass them into that function however you want and it should compare and set the heights the way you mentioned